# how to get all data from jeasyui datagrid

Tags: datagrid, jquery-easyui

I am using jeasyui datagrid with pagination. I need to get all data from datagrid. I tried getData() method but it gives only current page data i need to get all pages data.

here is the my code i tried

```
 var data = $("#dg").datagrid("getData").rows;
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Could you please use the "Edit" button below your question to add the code for column filtering that's not working?

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. i added my code to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I know its late, But this would work.

*Returns the loaded data.*

```
var data = $("#dg").datagrid("getData");
```

or

*Return the current page rows.*

```
var data = $("#dg").datagrid("getRows");
```

Comment: Nope, getData returns current page only.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your datagrid with `pagination:true` then you will always get the current page. if you want to get all the data the you should set `pagination:false`. But remember, this will be show all the data without pagination.

Comment: var data = $("#dg").datagrid("getData"); this may help, even though pagination is true.